# Pattern matching - value is not a member on a bound variable

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, pattern-matching, scala-compiler

I am working my way through Scala (ver. `2.13.2`), and here I've defined a simple linked list with a trait `ListSeq`. Also, I wanted to override a `toString` method for pretty-printing. For this, I decided to use pattern-matching. The desired result can be seen in `assert` cases

```
sealed trait ListSeq {
    override def toString: String = s"[$elemSequence]"
    private def elemSequence: String = {
        this match {
            case ListPair(hd, tl @ ListPair(_, _)) => s"$hd, ${tl.elemSequence}"
            case ListPair(hd, EmptyList) => s"$hd"
            case EmptyList => ""
        }
    }
}
case class ListPair(head: Int, tail: ListSeq) extends ListSeq
case object EmptyList extends ListSeq

object ListSeqExample extends App {
    val seq1 = ListPair(1, ListPair(2, ListPair(3, EmptyList)))
    val seq2 = EmptyList
    
    assert(seq1.toString == "[1, 2, 3]")
    assert(seq2.toString == "[]")
}
```

### The problem

This code doesn't compile, the error is:

```
value elemSequence is not a member of ListPair
            case ListPair(hd, tl @ ListPair(_, _)) => s"$hd, ${tl.elemSequence}"
```

It is not clear to me why this error appears. From what I know, Scala can match on nested fields and bind the fields to a variable - like what is done in `case ListPair(hd, tl @ ListPair(_, _))`. But from the error message, it seems that it cannot guess the type of bound object (`ListPair`)

### Weird behavior

Another interesting thing is - if I redefine the `ListSeq` in the following way - by removing the `elemSequence` method, and all string creation is done in `toString` - **there is no error**:

```
sealed trait ListSeq {
    override def toString: String = this match {
        case ListPair(hd, tl @ ListPair(_, _)) => s"$hd, ${tl.toString}"
        case ListPair(hd, EmptyList) => s"$hd"
        case EmptyList => ""
    }
}
```

I know that the result of `toString` will be slightly different (no braces), but it is not the main point here.

### The question

Why is there an error in one case, while it happily compiles in another?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It returns an error because `elemSequence` is a `private` method defined in `ListSeq` so it is not visible in `ListPair`.

One solution could be to change the visibility to `protected` (and add the modifier final so the child classes cannot `override` the method):

```
sealed trait ListSeq {
    override def toString: String = s"[$elemSequence]"
    final protected def elemSequence: String = {
        this match {
            case ListPair(hd, tl @ ListPair(_, _)) => s"$hd, ${tl.elemSequence}"
            case ListPair(hd, EmptyList) => s"$hd"
            case EmptyList => ""
        }
    }
}
case class ListPair(head: Int, tail: ListSeq) extends ListSeq
case object EmptyList extends ListSeq

object ListSeqExample extends App {
    val seq1 = ListPair(1, ListPair(2, ListPair(3, EmptyList)))
    val seq2 = EmptyList
    
    assert(seq1.toString == "[1, 2, 3]")
    assert(seq2.toString == "[]")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a private method. Those are not inherited or accessible by subclasses (in Scala or in Java).

Changing it to protected or public or package private will fix this.